# Why animation does not work for [hidden] in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a two block that must toggle.

```
<div [hidden]="isVisible$ | async" [@inOutAnimation]>
<div [hidden]="!(isVisible$ | async)" [@inOutAnimation]>
```

And animation inside component:

```
  animations: [
    trigger("inOutAnimation", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }),
        animate("1s ease-out", style({ height: 300, opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        style({ height: 300, opacity: 1 }),
        animate("1s ease-in", style({ height: 0, opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

When I change `isVisible$` the `divs` are changed. But animation does not work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try to use *ngIf instead of [hidden]

look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976049/angular2-animated-hidden-element

Comment: I can not use ngif beacuse components should not recreated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hidden` attribute does not support animations, since it doesn't make any transition between the two states.

I recently faced the same issue and did this :

```js
animations: [
    trigger('contentExpansion', [
      state('collapsed', style({height: '0', opacity: 0})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*', opacity: 1})),
      transition('collapsed <=> expanded', [
        animate('300ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)')
      ]),
    ]),
],
```

You can notice I used [Angular animation states](https://angular.io/api/animations/state).
In the HTML :

```html
<div class="card-header" (click)="collapsed = !collapsed">
```

In the component :

```js
@Input() collapsed: boolean = true;
```

Comment: Tahank you, so you use [hidden]?

Comment: In the current example, I am just using my state variable `collapsed`. But if you want to keep that 'hidden' logic, I recommand you to use `*ngIf` instead.

Comment: It does not work for me, could you provide HTML?

Comment: I dont see how do you use `collapsed` in templlate